# How to intercept http Form Data using WebView Android

Tags: android, http, http-headers, android-webview

I have to implement Authentication. I use Webview android. When login web page is opened user enters email and password and click "login" button. After that the web page is redirected to Call back Url, on this step I have to intercept only Authentication token in webview and nothing more. The Authentication token what I need to get is storeged in the request Form Data.
I can see the Authentication token in the browser if I:

1.Open the developer tools (click f12 on keyboard).

2.Select "Network"

3.Select "All"

4.Select file in the "Name" tab

5.Select "Headers"

and I can see the window as is shown on image and in this window is shown Authentication token
[image]

How can I get Authentication token form Form data using WebVeiw?

This is example how iOS developers implemented it:

In Swift, our web view callback gives us a thing called a `NavigationAction`.
We first check whether `navigationAction.request.url` is
`..//identity/userAuthenticated`.
If so, then we parse `navigationAction.request.httpBody` to get the auth code.

Comment: Can you first tell where and when you tried to intercept the data to be posted but did not succeed? Add all info to your post please.

Comment: You do not have to intercept pass and email that the user typed in? But a response from the server? Then what exactly do you get back from the server that you wanna intercept? Is it displayed by the webview normally? `at this stage` is pretty unclear to me. Intercepting form data is done when form data is posted. Not when you receive something from server.

Comment: @blackapps I edited my question

Comment: You have not answered my questions in a way that was conclusive to me. I know nothing more by your answer.